# How to send input to console application from PowerShell

Tags: powershell, adb, console-application

After starting an adb shell console application with a powershell script,  I would like to automate the user inpute to this console application.

```
adb shell "/usr/bin/console_app"
```

Is there a way to have the powershell script enter those console inputs as well an don't have it wait for the user inputs?

Something like:

```
adb shell "/usr/bin/console_app"
sleep -s 5 <# wait for app to start#>
1 <# user input for menu selection#>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My preferred solution:

```
$startInfo = New-Object 'System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo' -Property @{
    FileName = "adb"
    Arguments = "shell", "/usr/bin/console_app"
    UseShellExecute = $false
    RedirectStandardInput = $true
}
$process = [System.Diagnostics.Process]::Start($startInfo)
Start-Sleep -Seconds 5
$process.StandardInput.WriteLine("1")
```

You could also try to wait for the application to finish starting by reading the output:

```
# set this on the ProcessStartInfo:
RedirectStandardOutput = $true

# wait while application returns stdout
while ($process.StandardOutput.ReadLine()) { }
```

The following will also work with non-console applications, but might not work well within non-interactive contexts:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName 'System.Windows.Forms', 'Microsoft.VisualBasic'
$id = (Start-Process "adb" -ArgumentList "shell", "/usr/bin/console_app" -PassThru).Id
Start-Sleep -Seconds 5
[Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::AppActivate($id)
[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("1~")
```

Comment: Great, the first suggested solution worked in my .ps1 skript. I will try the second solution as well. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Follow up question: Is there a way to get somehow feeback from adb if the application has been started in order to replace the simple Start-sleep?

Comment: @T.Richter One thing you can try is reading from the standard output. I added it to my answer, this should get you started.